# Highlight active tab in elementary terminal window

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I generally open multiple terminal window using ctrl+shift+t.
But since all tabs has same color, its very difficult to recognize which is the active tab.
Is ther a way to change color of active tab??

Comment: I think this functionality is not available right now in terminal. It might be `change request` or `enhacement` for eOS.

You can see over [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elementary/terminal/master/data/screenshot.png) that it have little highlighting. Is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a white underline on the active tab?

Regardless you should probably install a different terminal emulator if you want more customizing ability. You can use Terminator.